# Comparing fix fields in quickfix for python

Tags: quickfix

How can I compare two fix fields in quickfix for python? I've tried this:

```
execType = fix.ExecType(fix.Exectype_NEW)
if execType == fix.ExecType(fix.ExecType_NEW):
   print 'success'
```

, but didn't succed. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Going through quickfix.py, i realized that the CharField class doesn't have a dunder method eq, whereas the StringField class does. On the other hand, the getValue() method is not in StringField, but it appears in CharField. I can't seem to find an all-encompassing way of dealing with the fields....

Comment: What kind of error are you getting when you don't succeed?

Comment: i don't get any errors.....basically, the comparison returns false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what `fix.ExecType(fix.Exectype_NEW)` is trying to do, but maybe your problem is you aren't getting the right part of the message first.

With `message` as the message coming in from your counterparty, you can do:

`message.getHeader().getField(fix.MsgType())`

and if the field, say Symbol (55), is in the message body (not header):

`message.getField(fix.Symbol())`.

If the field is in a group you need to do more to get them. If you are trying to get `ExecType` make sure that the message actually contains this field (e.g. 35=8).

Does that help at all?